# What does this line of CSS do?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

```
*:first-child+html .clearfix{zoom:1px;}
```

What does this do? It was turning everything into 1px in Internet Explorer 7. This was in my WordPress theme's style.css (designed by ElegantTheme). What is it suppose to do? I think it's a bug in Internet Explorer that's causing it to render incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

That gives [layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) to all `.clearfix` elements in IE7 using the non-standard `zoom` property, so that layouts fall together properly where IE7 otherwise wouldn't make them.

The `*:first-child + html` selector, or simply `* + html`, exploits IE7's delusion that there's some element that comes before `html`. [It is a hack.](http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/filters/star-plus-html)

I think the declaration should have read `zoom: 1;` instead of `zoom: 1px;`.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it won't actually be setting `hasLayout` because of the `px`

Comment: @thirtydot: According to the article I link to, `zoom: any other value than 'normal'` grants layout. The `px` is causing IE7 to downsize everything to an area of 1 square pixel, as the OP describes.

Comment: I think it means "any [valid value]". I tested this with IE9's IE7 Standards Mode: http://jsfiddle.net/XRXa4/ / http://fiddle.jshell.net/XRXa4/show/light/ - alerts "true / false". I think what the OP meant by `"turning everything into 1px"` is that his floats weren't being cleared in IE7 (due to the invalid `zoom` value).

Comment: @thirtydot: You're right, my bad. I've been writing so many incorrect comments lately... I need to learn to shut up sometimes.